# Chrome window buttons hidden when Save As / Open window appear

Tags: mac, macos, google-chrome, window-manager

I am having issue with chrome, when ever I want to download or upload any item, the default window which appears, I cant see the buttons of that window, they kind of go down the dock, until unless I click the browse button (marked in black) to collapse the window and scroll back full again, only then I can see the buttons.

Is it issue with chrome?

Check screen shot for details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 = Switch to fullscreen

Option 2 = Autohide the dock

When you try to save this time resize the dialog window so its not so low and continue saving.

It should remember the same size when you switch back to your normal screen or dock settings.